# Question about the basin of attraction of the origin of the following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Regarding of the following system :
$$\begin{cases}
\dot x=-x^3 \\
\dot y=-x^2y-y-z^2y \\ 
\dot z=-\sin z \\ 
\end{cases}$$

I am working to show that the point $(0,0,0)$ is asymptotically stable and find its attractiveness basin.

---

My attempt: I consider the Lyapunov function:
$$
V(x,y,z)=x^4+y^2+(1-\cos z)
$$
Note that $V(0,0,0)=0$ and for all $z\neq n\pi$ and $x, y$,
$$
V(x,y,z)> x^4+y^2\ge 0
$$

Since
$$
\dot V(x,y,z)=-4x^6-2y^2(x^2+z^2+1)-\sin^2 z\le -4x^6-2y^2-\sin^2 z<0,
$$
where $\nabla V=[4x^3, 2y, \sin z]^T$, for all $(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$.

Then $V$ is negative definite. We can conclude that the equilibrium point is asymptotically stable in a region around the origin.

However, it seems that it does not have its attractiveness basin. I am confused about this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connectivity component of the origin of the set $\Omega_C=\{ x:V(x)< C \}$ is an estimation of the region of attraction of $\{0\}$ (in the sense that any trajectory starting at some $x_0\in \Omega_C$ tends to the origin without leaving $\Omega_C$) if $\forall x\in\Omega_C\setminus \{0\}\;\; \dot V(x)<0$. This follows from the procedure of proving the Lyapunov’s stability theorem.

In this problem $\dot V$ is negative everywhere except for the points $(0,0,\pi n)$, $n\in\mathbb Z$, so any of the sets $\Omega_C=\{ x:V(x)< C \}$ that does not contain the points $(0,0,\pi n)$ except for $(0,0,0)$, is an estimation of the region of attraction. It is enough here to check the points $(0,0,\pm\pi)$. Since $V(0,0,\pi)=V(0,0,-\pi)=2$, the largest of these sets is
$$
\Omega_2= \{ x:V(x)< 2 \}=\{ (x,y,z): x^4+y^2+(1-\cos z)<2\}.
$$

[image: \Omega_2]
                  Pic.1 The set $\Omega_2$. Red, green and blue arrows are coordinate axes $x$, $y$, $z$.

Not this entire set is an estimation of the region of attraction, but only the connectivity component of the origin, so the final answer is
$$
\Omega_2^c=\{ (x,y,z): x^4+y^2+(1-\cos z)<2\; \wedge 
\; |z|<\pi\}.
$$
[image: \Omega_2^c]
                  Pic.2 The set $\Omega_2^c$.

Comment: @Moo I used the `isosurface` function from Matlab

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering what the equivalent would be in Mathematica and it looks like https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why the basin of attraction is $\Omega_2$? I am just confused why do we need to set $V(x,y,z)<2$? Also, why the final answer is $\Omega_2^c$ but not $\Omega$?

Comment: @Hermi According to the idea of ​​proving the Lyapunov’s theorem, inside $\Omega_2$ $V(x)$ decreases along the trajectories of the system, i.e. $\dot V(x(t))=\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t))<0$. The trajectory cannot leave the set, since otherwise $V(x(t))$ would increase when moving along the trajectory. It is also proven that $V(x(t))$ decreases down to zero, but explaining this would be too long for comment. $\Omega_2^c$ is taken because inside other components there are points $(0,0,\pi n)$, where $V(x)=0$ and the trajectory can tend to these points instead of the origin when $V(x)$ decreases to zero.

Comment: @AVK Thank you! Can I ask why can we say the original point is globally asymptotically stable? Because the condition $V'(x)<0$ can only say the original point is asymptotically stable, right?

Comment: @Hermi If there are several equilibrium points, then none of them can be globally asymptotically stable, since from one point the trajectory cannot tend to the others.

Comment: @AVK Thank you! But I think that is not enough. How to show this region $\Omega_2^c$ is compact and positively invariant set with respect to $f$? Then we apply LaSalle's principle, $\Omega_2^c$ is the largest invariant set in $E=\{x \in \Omega_2^c: \dot{V}(x)=0\}$?

Comment: @Hermi It's not compact. Why do you need compactness? LaSalle's principle is not needed too. Positive invariance of $\Omega_2$ is shown in the proof of the Lyapunov's theorem. This is one of the basic ideas of stability theory. As for $\Omega_2^c$, it is also positively invariant, since the trajectory cannot jump from one connected component to another (otherwise it would have to get out of $\Omega_2$ first, but then $\Omega_2$ would not be positively invariant).

Comment: @AVK Recall that Lasalle's principle
"For $D\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ open let $f:D\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be $C^{1}(D;\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Consider $\dot{x}=f(x)$ and let $\Omega\subset{D}$ be compact and positively invariant and $V\in C^{1}(D;\mathbb{R})$ with $\dot V(x)\leq 0$ on $\Omega$. Let $E:=\{x\in\Omega| \dot V(x)=0\}$ and let $M\subseteq E$ be the largest **positively** invariant set in $E$. The every solution starting in $\Omega$ appraches $M$ for $t\to\infty$." It seems that we need $\Omega=\{x: V(x)\le C\}$ is compact, right?

Comment: @Hermi What is your question? How to apply LaSalle's principle to solve this problem? No way. LaSalle's principle extends Lyapunov's theorem to the case where the set $E$ consists of more than just isolated equilibrium points. It is not needed here, as I wrote. Here, as you can see, $M=E=\{ (0,0,\pi n),\;n\in\mathbb Z\}$ consists of isolated equilibrium points; therefore, the fact that the trajectories tends towards them has already been proven by the Lyapunov’s theorem (more precisely, by its proof :)).

Comment: If you absolutely need to solve this problem using LaSalle, take any of the sets $\Omega_C^c$, which are the origin connectivity components of $\Omega_C=\{ x:\; V(x)\le C\}$, $0<C<2$, and apply LaSalle's principle to it. Although this is a bad solution (showing that the solver did not understand stability theory well)

Comment: @AVK Can you please see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803300/how-to-prove-the-following-region-is-positively-invariant? I found the solution to this question in the textbook. It says that the whole region $|z|<\pi$ is the basin of attraction.