# How to prove the following region is positively invariant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I just consider another Lyapunov function as in question [Question about the basin of attraction of the origin of the following ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798847/question-about-the-basin-of-attraction-of-the-origin-of-the-following-ode)

> Regarding of the following system :
> $$\begin{cases}
> \dot x=-x^3 \\
> \dot y=-x^2y-y-z^2y \\ 
> \dot z=-\sin z \\ 
> \end{cases}$$
> Show that the point $(0,0,0)$ is asymptotically stable and find its attractiveness basin.

Consider $V(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and then
$$
\dot V(x,y,z)=-2x^4-2y^2(x^2+z^2+1)-2z\sin z
$$
which is strictly less than zero for $|z|<\pi$ except for the origin. Hence, it is asymptotically.

This is one example in the page 198 in textbook [Morris W. Hirsch, Stephen Smale and Robert L. Devaney (Auth.) - Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos-Academic Press](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiDwJqYv7WCAxU2MDQIHcGLB2UQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Feclass.uoa.gr%2Fmodules%2Fdocument%2Ffile.php%2FMATH626%2FMorris%2520W.%2520Hirsch%252C%2520Stephen%2520Smale%2520and%2520Robert%2520L.%2520Devaney%2520%2528Auth.%2529%2520-%2520Differential%2520Equations%252C%2520Dynamical%2520Systems%252C%2520and%2520an%2520Introduction%2520to%2520Chaos-Academic%2520Press%2520%25282012%2529.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3_f1sBfocWDkOYWhBT5ReX&opi=89978449).

It says that

> In particular, any solution that begins in the region $|z|<\pi$ must remain trapped in this region for all time. Moreover, we can conclude that the basin of attraction of the origin is the entire region $|z|<\pi$. Any solutions that starts insider a sphere of radius $r<\pi$ must tend to the origin. Outsider of the sphere of radius $\pi$ and between the planes $|z|=\pi$, the function $V$ is still strictly decreasing. Since solutions are trapped between these two planes, it follows that they too must tend to the origin.

---

For the first part, since
$$
\Omega_1=\{(x,y,z): V(x,y,z) \mbox{ and } |z|<\pi\}
$$
is positively invariant, then we can prove that "Any solutions that starts insider a sphere of radius $r<\pi$ must tend to the origin.".

**Question: But how to prove that the second that solution starting from the outside of the sphere will converge to the origin?**

Comment: You don't. Per the claim the behavior outside the sphere is undetermined. Per the previous discussion, $x$ and $y$ converge unconditionally to zero, while $z$ converges to $2k\pi$ from any point with $|z_0-2k\pi|<\pi$. Restricting the claim to the sphere is only done to compare it with similar claims, or, if you want, theoretical predictions, about other systems where the Lyapunov function is the only or by far easiest theoretical tool.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The quote after "It says that" is, in some sense, a proof

Comment: Are you asking why $V$ is strictly decreasing? Or why solutions are trapped between the planes? Or how it follows that they must tend to the origin?

Comment: @AVK Exactly! I am confused why "Outsider of the sphere of radius, all solutions converges to the origin."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question, since for $-\pi+\epsilon<z<0$ (resp. $0<z<\pi-\epsilon$), the function $\sin z$ is increasing (resp. decreasing). Then the solution all converges to the origin.